# Why is this IgnoreRoute call matching these requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, ignoreroute

I've got a localization httphandler that's running in the context of my ASP.Net MVC2 Content folder (part of what it's doing is compiling .less files that are in /Content/css). My default route for this particular set of requests looks like this:

```
context.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

context.MapRoute(
    "Area_default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { controller = new VirtualDirectoryConstraint("VDirectory1") },
    new string[] { "Namespace.One.MVC" }
);
```

(As an aside - I don't think it's relevant, but just in case - the VirtualDirectoryConstraint rejects matches on this route if the request is not coming from the passed-in application path/virtual directory)

With this configuration a call to `http://server.net/VDirectory1/Content/css/LessCompiler.axd` fails because there's no ContentController class.  All well and good.

When I add

```
context.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{Content}/{*pathInfo}");
```

that call succeeds, but subsequent calls to

```
http://server.net/VDirectory1/Localization/ClientScript/en-US.js
```

and

```
http://server.net/VDirectory1/Authorization/ClientScript
```

fail. Looking at Phil Haack's RouteDebugger tool, those calls are matching the Content IgnoreRoute route:

```
True    {Content}/{*pathInfo}   (null)  (null)  (null)
```

and are therefore not being routed to the LocalizationController and AuthorizationController, respectively.

Clearly I'm misunderstanding something about how the IgnoreRoute is supposed to be used and why that particular IgnoreRoute is matching those requests. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't your IgnoreRoute use `Content` instead of `{Content}` ?

```
context.Routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
```

At the moment, `{Content}` is probably being expanded as a variable to nothing, which makes the pathinfo match everything.